# How can I use the BCP Command in Linux?

Tags: linux, bcp

I want to use the `bcp` command in Linux as the following:

```
bcp "EasyCash.dbo.user" out "[EasyCash].[dbo].[user].dat" -q -c -t "<EOFD>"
         -r "<EORD>" -Usa -P123456 -S192.168.1.5
```

The message in Linux shows like that:

```
-base bcp: command not found
```

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: What "bcp" command do you mean?  Are you referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx   ?

Comment: At a minimum, you need to tell us what version of Linux and what database you're trying to access.  It looks like you don't have the package installed that provides this command.

Comment: Try typing "which bcp" does it return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have whatever package on your machine that contains the `bcp` executable, try typing

```
locate bcp | grep bin
```

and look at the output to see if this executable exists on your computer but is not in your path.  If this does not return anything, then you are missing the executable.  If this turns up something, then you can try to run it using the whole path.

Answer (score 6):

You can use FreeTDS and its FreeBCP utility. It's comparable to MSSQL Server's bcp.exe http://www.freetds.org/

Answer (score -1):

That example sure looks like MSSQL's BCP command )(-Usa... the 'sa' user). MSSQL is a Windows only product.

Comment: When I Googled, I did find other references to some Linux "bcp" commands related to databases ... but yes, I was thinking the same thing.  Without more input from the OP, who knows?

Comment: this looks like a comment to me and not an answer to the question

Answer (score -1):

See the Sybase ASE documentation for full details of how to install, deploy and use the bcp command. Or ask your DBA.